# Flatten an array of objects into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of an object with dynamic keys

```
response = [{"1": 1}, {"2": 1}, {"3": 1}, {"4": 0}, {"5": 0}];
```

I want to flatten this array of an object into a single array

```
Output = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I tried the following:

```
const test2 = this.response.map(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
        return obj[key]
    })
});

const test = this.response.reduce(function(prev, curr){
    console.log(curr)
    return (curr) ? prev.concat(curr): prev;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with `.concat()`:

```js
let data =   [{"1": 1}, {"2": 1}, {"3": 1}, {"4": 0}, {"5": 0}];
      
let result = [].concat(...data.map(Object.values));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just use map and object.values

```js
response = [{"1": 1}, {"2": 1}, {"3": 1}, {"4": 0}, {"5": 0}]
const vals = response.map(o => Object.values(o)[0])

console.log(vals)
```

Comment: Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'. when used on the chart but works perfect on the concept

Comment: No clue why that error would occur with that code above.

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce and `for..in` to loop over the object

```js
let response = [{
    "1": 1
  },
  {
    "2": 1
  },
  {
    "3": 1
  },
  {
    "4": 0
  },
  {
    "5": 0
  }
]

let k = response.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  for (let keys in curr) {
    acc.push(curr[keys])

  }
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
response = [{"1": 1},{"2": 1},{"3": 1},{"4": 0},{"5": 0}]

var newArray = []
for (element of response) {
  Object.keys(element).map(key => {
    newArray.push(element[key])
  })
}


console.log(newArray)
```